# Is there any advantage to incorporating some sort of business for the purpose of holding and trading equity holdings?

Tags: united-states, stocks, limited-liability-company

What options are there for incorporating a holding vehicle for equity positions rather than owning them in my own personal name?

Answer (score 1):

An issuer company, for the purpose of investing, would be subject to investment company regulation. The advantage to this type of company is to raise funding from outside investors.

A non-issuer company, for the purpose of investing, would be subject to broker/dealer registration. The advantage to this type of company is to bring particular talented traders into one organization by rewarding the traders with percentage partnerships.

Now there is a 21% corporate tax rate but distributions from a corporate tax structure involve double taxation of distributions. Most trading companies use a higher-rate pass-though-taxation but avoid double taxation of distributions.

But an individual investor probably doesn't need a corporate structure because futures traders have an advantaged capital-gain tax rate while one-year equity holders also have an advantaged capital-gain tax rate.

Now an issuer company with an investment portfolio, but with a purpose other than investing, can avoid being classified as an investment company by having a portfolio that is 60% Treasury securities. Then if there is trading of the issuer shares, a 21% corporate tax rate might be chosen along with a policy of no distributions. Similarly, a non-issuer company could avoid being classified as a broker/dealer by having a purpose other than investing and by having a portfolio that is 60% Treasury securities.

Comment: The IRS has a trader-status tax accounting for individual traders making hundreds of trades per day. I would put a company like that on an individual's Schedule C and use the Schedule C as a rationale for not being subject to broker/dealer registration. A proprietor company can go on a Schedule C and a single-member LLC can go on a Schedule C.

Comment: A trading or holding company that is a C-corp with 5 or fewer shareholders could be classified as a personal-holding-company and face tax penalties, So the trading company needs to be a pass-through company. But a trading company issuing shares to the public could be subject to investment-company regulation. Or a C-corp that has a purpose other than investing, but that has a large portfolio in addition to the 60% Treasury securities, could be subject to accumulated-earnings-tax if the portfolio is not related to the business and if dividends are not paid-out. But C-corp dividends = double tax.

Comment: A trading company might be subject to broker/dealer registration but that's according to securities regulators and not according to tax authorities. According to tax authorities trading or investing is passive income.

Comment: What about the advantage of limiting liability in case of a blowup of a leveraged portfolio?

Comment: I did mention single-member LLC in the comments.

Comment: I just thought it was odd that for a question about possible advantages of forming a company, the answer focused on taxes and not on risk/leverage/etc. I think a primary reason people form a company is so they're not personally liable if the business goes bankrupt. And people *do* sometimes go bankrupt when trading stocks aggressively, so the obvious question is whether forming a company would be a loophole allowing you to trade with high leverage and then just "walk away" in the event of big losses.

Comment: The IRS considers a trader to be someone who trades continuously throughout the day and five days a week. If the IRS is not satisfied then the company would need to meet securities regulation to get the IRS to accept the company. How to form a trading or investing company is the first step.